# (Ghidra) How to get the parameter name given a Function object and the storage location as a register string?

Tags: ghidra

Given an instance of something that implements `ghidra.program.model.listing.Function`, and the register as a string (e.g. `x0`) how can I get the name of the argument (e.g. `param1`)?

Answer (score -1):

The first way I found is (as Kotlin code)

```
function.parameters.first { it.variableStorage.register.toString() == "x0" }.name
```

i.e. go through the parameters and find the first (and hopefully only one), that has a storage location with the string representation `x0`.

This feels somewhat hacky, but should at least work. The whole expression type checks, so it should cover basically all cases, and I am not sure if there can ever be a case where somehow multiple parameters are stored in the same register that have the same string representation.